# Implement LocalNotification

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'am a novice in Xamarin. I am looking for a way to implement localnotification to my crossform app.

Here is the code I get from the Xamarin web site : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/

```
// Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (this)
    .SetContentTitle ("Sample Notification")
    .SetContentText ("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
    .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);

// Build the notification:
Notification notification = builder.Build();

// Get the notification manager:
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

// Publish the notification:
const int notificationId = 0;
notificationManager.Notify (notificationId, notification);
```

I just want to know how I can , active notification when I push on a button

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Forms app or a Xamarin.Android app?

Comment: Copy the codes, you posted into a button click event. So you click the button, notification will show.

Comment: @Heshan is it for Xammarin.forms app

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`AddAction(Notification.Action action)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Notification+Builder.AddAction/p/Android.App.Notification+Action/) function. `Notification.Action` Must be created by [`Notification.Action.Builder`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Notification+Action+Builder/)

Basic Example:

```
var actionBuilder = new Notification.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification_action, "Click me", someActionIntent);

// Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (this)
    .SetContentTitle ("Sample Notification")
    .SetContentText ("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
    .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_notification)
    .AddAction(actionBuilder.Build());
```

Mind that you must initialize `someActionIntent` first of all.

Comment: @ad1Diama  Thanks ,is there a way to have it for a cross form app ? Or it is only for android

Comment: @hugo sory, not sure

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a unified way to display Local Notifications, use the following plugin by James Montemagno. Install the plugin in your PCL and Android project.
[Local Notifications Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Notifier/)

```
private void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Xamarin.Forms` App, You need [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to accomplish that:

1. Create an interface in your PCL(`ILocalNotificationService.cs`):

   ```
   public interface ILocalNotificationService
   {
       void ShowLocalNotification(string title, string text, string icon);
   }
   ```
2. In local `Xamarin.Android` project, create a class (`LocalNotificationServiceImplementation.cs`) to implement `ILocalNotificationService` and inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` then add `assembly:Dependency` attribute on top of the namespace:

   ```
   [assembly:Dependency(typeof(LocalNotificationServiceImplementation))]
   namespace LocalNotificationDemo.Droid
   {
       public class LocalNotificationServiceImplementation :Java.Lang.Object, ILocalNotificationService
       {
           public void ShowLocalNotification(string title, string text, string icon)
           {

               // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
               Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Forms.Context)
                   .SetContentTitle(title)
                   .SetContentText(text);

               if (icon == "ic_notification")
               {
                   builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);
               }

               // Build the notification:
               Notification notification = builder.Build();

               // Get the notification manager:
               NotificationManager notificationManager =
                   Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

               // Publish the notification:
               const int notificationId = 0;
               notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Inside PCL's button click event handler, call the dependency service like below:

   ```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().ShowLocalNotification("My Title", "Hello World! This is my first notification!", "ic_notification");
   }
   ```

Notes: Xamarin calls the default constructor of Dependency Service class, so context can't be passed through constructor, but xamarin offers `Forms.Context`, which stands for the current context of the activity.

Comment: I have tried to implement you solution but nothings happen there is not notification when I clicked on a button

Comment: xaml:<ContentPage.Content>


        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="20">

            <Button Text="notifyme" FontSize="25"  Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    
        </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>

Comment: @hugo [Here](https://github.com/elvisxia/LocalNotificationDemo) is the complete demo codes, please have a try. I'm using VS2017 for development. If there is still no notification, please try it on other devices.